# In GEE, how to reduce resolution to get a map of "distances to pixel class" without holes?

Tags: google-earth-engine, resolution

I'm struggling with Google Earth Engine limitations on distance calculations.

I'm using the ESA landcover map, which natively has a resolution of 10 m. I want to calculate the distance between a hexagonal grid and pixels marked as 'water' in this image. More specifically, I want an average *per* hexagon, representing the average distance of that hexagon to the nearest source of water

I have a code who in principle would work, except that there is a limit on the number of pixels GEE is willing to calculate distances to (512). Thus, the options are either to reduce the radius, and leave gaps in the map, or increase pixel resolution. However, I can't seem to do the latter, even using reduceResolution.

```
// Example polygon in feature Collection
var emptypolys = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([
    [-65.12327127375431,-2.8836114621693048],
    [-65.12327127375431,-2.8527277618265834],
    [-65.15001697744425,-2.837285883292355],
    [-65.17676264363732,-2.852727710546676],
    [-65.17676264363732,-2.8836114394249686],
    [-65.15001697744425,-2.899053304102115],
    [-65.12327127375431,-2.8836114621693048]
])));

var landcover = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/WorldCover/v100');

var distwater = landcover
                  .first()
                  .eq(80) // get binary image of water-no_waterpixels
                  .reduceResolution({
                      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                      bestEffort:true, 
                      maxPixels:2000
                   }) //Does nothing, apparently
                  .distance(ee.Kernel.euclidean({radius:10000,units:'meters'})); //fails for too many pixels without reduceResolution 

var var reduced = distwater.reduceRegions(emptypolys,ee.Reducer.mean()); //fails for too many pixels
```

It seems that `reduceResolution` does allow me to at least plot the map in code editor with `Map.addLayer(distwater)` but whenever I call for `reduced` than it produces the too many pixels error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong, and why I can't reduce the resolution on this image?